# For a given interval of years to get the number of days per week(mon, tue, web,...,sun) of the year

Tags: oracle, dayofweek, monthcalendar

I want to find all solutions for this "For a given interval of years to get the number of days per week(mon, tue, web,...,sun) of the year"

does anybody know other answer?  share it please ;)

this is my query:)

```
WITH dat AS
(SELECT &&start_year + level - 1 cur_year, DECODE(MOD(&start_year + level - 1, 4), 0, 0, 1) no_leap, 
TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01.01.'||TO_CHAR(&start_year + level - 1)), 'D')) d
FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL < &end_year - &start_year + 2)
SELECT cur_year,
51 + DECODE(no_leap, 1, DECODE(d, 1, 2, 1), DECODE(d, 1, 2, 7, 2, 1)) mon,
51 + DECODE(no_leap, 1, DECODE(d, 2, 2, 1), DECODE(d, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1)) tue,
51 + DECODE(no_leap, 1, DECODE(d, 3, 2, 1), DECODE(d, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1)) wed,
51 + DECODE(no_leap, 1, DECODE(d, 4, 2, 1), DECODE(d, 4, 2, 3, 2, 1)) thu,
51 + DECODE(no_leap, 1, DECODE(d, 5, 2, 1), DECODE(d, 5, 2, 4, 2, 1)) fri,
51 + DECODE(no_leap, 1, DECODE(d, 6, 2, 1), DECODE(d, 6, 2, 5, 2, 1)) sat,
51 + DECODE(no_leap, 1, DECODE(d, 7, 2, 1), DECODE(d, 7, 2, 6, 2, 1)) sun
FROM dat;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be taking advantage of Oracle's date-arithmetic. When you minus two dates from each other a number is returned, the number of days between the two dates. If there's not an integer difference then the actual difference is returned:

```
SQL> select sysdate - to_date('20120504 15', 'yyyymmdd hh24') from dual;

SYSDATE-TO_DATE('2012050415','YYYYMMDDHH24')
--------------------------------------------
                                  3.76489583
```

Please note that this does not include `timestamp`, only `date` data-types. Doing `timestamp` arithmetic returns an `interval` data-type.

Most of a solution would be

```
with dates as ( 
  select to_char(to_date('&start_year','yyyy') + level, 'fmDAY') as days
    from dual
  connect by level < to_date('&end_year','yyyy') - to_date('&start_year','yyyy')
          )
  select ...
```

Note the [`fm` modifier](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00216) of the format model; this removes trailing spaces.

As a general rule, when dealing with dates it is always preferable to use *dates*, rather than numbers or characters. Your `connect by` clause `CONNECT BY LEVEL < &end_year - &start_year + 2`, though simple has caused you to do a lot of extra work in order to get your solution to work.

Comment: hi Ben, your query just return the number of days in the interval year[start_year, end_year]. but i need to return the number of days (per week) for each year.